# How to fix this gradle dependency resolution error?

Tags: java, build, gradle, dependency-management

I am new to gradle and I am trying to use it for an existing java project.

I have created settings.gradle file in my root directory:

```
include ':datamodel'
include ':active'
include ':client'
include ':zero'
include ':toall'
```

and build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}
```

The build.gradle in datamodel looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.+'
}
```

When I run gradle build (version: 2.0) I get this failure

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':datamodel:compile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.+.
  Required by:
      MyRoot:datamodel:unspecified
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to your build script. Not as a part of `buildscript` closure where you can define where to look for dependencies required to execute your build script. You can do it in your top-level `build.gradle` using

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
```

More info [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0)

The maven repo looks like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and add `jcenter()` to dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

which will allow to search not only in `repo1.maven.org`